# How to synchronize Crowd groups to jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, atlassian-crowd

Say I have three groups in my crowd already:

- Managers
- Project A members
- Project B members

**Goal:** I want to synchronize these settings with Jenkins and make sure that:

- Managers - can do anything
- Project A members - have access only to Project A
- Project B members - surprise, should access only Project B

Crowd should play as "Master" role - therefore if someone moves from Project A to Project B, I want to move them only in Crowd and not care about Jenkins (where Jenkins should update itself)

Is there a possibility to do so without creating and managing roles and groups inside Jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after installing Jenkins and Crowd to test environment I realized this:

**Crowd sends data about groups automatically, all you need to do is to create the same groups in Jenkins**

All you need to do is to create the same groups in Jenkins as you have in Crowd.

So only one uncaught thing is that if in Crowd new group is created, you have to create that group also in Jenkins and give it proper rights. This luckily does not happen so often